# Using Coldfusion cfspreadsheet to format spreadsheet page properties

Tags: coldfusion, orientation, margin, spreadsheet, cfspreadsheet

I would like to format the spreadsheet as below but couldn't find the proper functions to do it with cfspreadsheet or independent spreadsheet() functions.

- set page orientation to either portrait or landscape
- set page margin

Please advise!

Comment: You can use the apache poi instead of cfspreadsheet.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743615/apache-poi-change-page-format-for-excel-worksheet for page orientation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Last I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8734181), there were no built-in functions for manipulating margins or orientation. You need to tap into the underlying POI functions.

Create a CF spreadsheet object, then grab a reference to the underlying POI worksheet (whose properties you want to change):

```
<cfset cfSheetObject = SpreadSheetNew()>
<cfset poiSheet = cfSheetObject.getWorkBook().getSheet("TheSheetName")>
```

Orientation can be changed through the sheet's [print properties](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPrintSetup.html#setLandscape%28boolean%29):

```
<cfset ps = poiSheet.getPrintSetup()>
<cfset ps.setLandscape(true)>
```

Use [`setMargin(margin, size)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setMargin%28short,%20double%29) to change the desired margin(s): `LeftMargin`, `RightMargin`, etcetera... For a complete list of margin names, see the field names in the [`Sheet` interface](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html).

```
<cfset poiSheet.setMargin( poiSheet.LeftMargin, 0.25)>
```